# Make Variable With Number of Unique Case by a Grouping Var

Tags: r, data.table

I want to create a variable indicating there is at least one observation in each two-way table of two variables

I am working with panel data and want to know which observations are part of a group not represented in every year.  Here is example data:

```
library( data.table)    
iris <- data.table( iris )
iris$grp <- sample( 1:15 , nrow( iris ) , replace=T)
```

I know how to create a table with the number of unique Species * Grp cells.  I know that I can merge this back on to the `data.table` but it seems like there must be an easy way to create a variable directly.  I have been trying to use the `length()` function but that isn't right.  Essentially I want N in this table to be a variable in my data table.  The answer needs to be in data.table

```
unique( iris[ , .( Species , grp ) ])[ , .N , by=Species]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need to join

```
iris[unique( iris[ , .( Species , grp ) ])[ , .N , by=Species],
     N := N, on = .(Species)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
iris[, N := uniqueN(grp), Species]
```

FWIW, `data.table:::unique.data.table` has a `by` argument so you can use `unique(iris, by=c("Species","grp"))` for `unique(iris[, .(Species, grp)])`